# Output DateTime date but no time using only CultureInfo

Tags: c#, datetime

My code:

```
dateObject.Value.ToString(Model.Culture)
```

`dateObject` is of type `DateTime?` while `Model.Culture` is of type `CultureInfo`.

The (culture dependent) output:

> 17/08/1960 00:00:00

I'd like to remove the `00:00:00` part without having to specify any format provider.
`Model.Culture` should contains the format for the date already while somewhere else (but where and how?) I'd like to specify **not** to output any time.

I was thinking to cast DateTime over a Date object but, unfortunately, there is no such object in C#.
Hardcoding the date format directly will result in the impossibility to create a dynamic and culture dependent program.

Comment: I don't understand. The `CultureInfo` *is* the `IFormatProvider`. Do you or don't you want to pass one?

Comment: Or did you mean "format string" and not "format provider"?

Comment: yep, I meant just the format provider but NOT the format string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*" without having to specify any format provider"* 
...
*"Hardcoding the date format directly will result in the impossibility to create a dynamic and culture dependent program."*

You can use the overload that enables to provide a format string **and** the culture:

```
string result = dateObject.Value.ToString("d", Model.Culture);
```

or you change the culture if that is desired/possible:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Model.Culture;
string result = dateObject.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
dateObject.Value.ToString("d", Model.Culture)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) it uses the current thread culture.

```
DateTime dateObject = DateTime.Now;
string s = dateObject.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following using string formatting

```
dateObject.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

[**DATE FORMATS**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)